# Error while accessing DLL interface from Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, dll

I have made one windows Form application in C#. I have added one DLL reference in that application and called method of that DLL. Its working fine. But when I have made web application and added reference of same DLL and tried to run then I am getting error as

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'XXXXX.XXXX' to interface type 'XXXXX.XXXX'. 
This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{2DEEB1D7-0B44-4142-9E7B-07477781696C}' failed due to the following error: Bad variable type. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020008 (DISP_E_BADVARTYPE)).
```

The method in DLL, I am calling from web application as

```
m_SSCP.StartUp("FilePath", "value1", "value2", 6553703, 0, out return_code);
```

So if I am calling same function from Web application and Windows form application, Is there any difference between these two operation?

I tried to search on net but I am not getting any proper help.

Comment: This sounds "dll specific" so check it's API/documentation. The exception seems to be pointing you in some specific direction already `Bad variable type`

Comment: @EdSF : Thanks for reply. But as I am using same DLL in windows form application it works fine.  I have passed the same variable values in Web application but still I am getting same error.

Comment: Well, I can only guess because there really isn't much to go on. An example would be FilePath - how you refer to paths/folders/files in Windows/desktop is *not* the same in IIS/ASP.Net.

Comment: When you added references to yor project, Interop was created in both cases. you can check in Object browser, if the Interop definitions are the same (type check)